# Why is a histogram for normal samples rougher near the mode than near the tail?

Tags: r, statistics, normal-distribution

I am trying to understand a particular behavior of the histogram of samples generated from `rnorm`.

```
set.seed(1)
x1 <- rnorm(1000L)
x2 <- rnorm(10000L)
x3 <- rnorm(100000L)
x4 <- rnorm(1000000L)

plot.hist <- function(vec, title, brks) {
  h <- hist(vec, breaks = brks, density = 10,
            col = "lightgray", main = title) 
  xfit <- seq(min(vec), max(vec), length = 40) 
  yfit <- dnorm(xfit, mean = mean(vec), sd = sd(vec)) 
  yfit <- yfit * diff(h$mids[1:2]) * length(vec) 
  return(lines(xfit, yfit, col = "black", lwd = 2))
}

par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
plot.hist(x1, title = 'Sample = 1E3', brks = 100)
plot.hist(x2, title = 'Sample = 1E4', brks = 500)
plot.hist(x3, title = 'Sample = 1E5', brks = 1000)
plot.hist(x4, title = 'Sample = 1E6', brks = 1000)
```

[image]

You will notice that **in each case** *(I am not making cross comparison; I know that as sample size gets larger the match between histogram and the curve is better)*, the histogram approximates the standard normal better towards the tails, but poorer towards the mode. Simply put, I'm trying to understand why **each** histogram is rougher in the middle compared to the tails. Is this an expected behavior or have I missed something basic?

Comment: That is a much clearer and better, title. I agree!

Comment: I agree. Your answer answers that my suspicions are invalid, but not the why part when viewed as a histogram. I was thinking of cross posting it on crossvalidated to get a statistical perspective

Comment: This is a *statistical* question, not a programming-related one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not just true for normal samples. If we had fixed bins (rather than data-determined ones as we normally do) and we  condition on the total number of observations, then the counts would be [multinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

The expected value of the count in bin *i* is then n·p(i) where p(i) is the proportion of the population density that falls in bin (i).

The variance of the count in bin *i* would then be n·p(i)·(1-p(i)). With many bins and a smooth non-peaky density like a normal, (1-p(i)) will be very close to 1; p(i) will typically be smallish (much smaller that 1/2).

[image: variance function for a bernoulli p(1-p) vs p]

The variance of the count (and hence the standard deviation of it) is an increasing function of the expected height:

With a fixed bin width the height is proportional to the expected count and the standard deviation of the bin-height is an increasing function of the height.

So this motivates exactly what  you see.

In practice it's not the case that the bin boundaries are fixed; as you add observations or generate a new sample they will change, but the number of bins changes fairly slowly as a function of the sample size (typically as the cube root, or sometimes as the log) and a more sophisticated analysis than the one here is required to get the exact form. However, the outcome is the same -- under commonly observed conditions the variance of the height of a bin typically increases monotonically with the height of the bin.

Comment: Could you please elaborate this sentence - 
`The variance of the count (and hence the standard deviation of it) is an increasing function of the expected height`.
I get an intuitive sense of what you are saying. But the meaning of the above sentence was not immediately obvious to me.

Comment: Given a fixed n and that p(i)<0.5, then as n.p(i) increases, so does n.p(i).(1-p(i)). This means the variance of the count in the bin increases when the expected count in the bin increases.

Comment: I understand. So, we define a statistic = count in each bin. Next, if x is the midpoint of the bin, we note that Var(statistic(x)) is the maximum when x = 0. Is that correct?

Pretty amazing to have Glen_b answer! Thank you.

Comment: In your particular case, if you had equal width bins and fixed bin-boundaries the bin that included 0 would have the highest variance of height, yes (you could do that by passing a list of bin boundaries to `breaks)`. More generally, with fixed and equal width bins, the bin encompassing the largest fraction of the distribution would have the highest variance of bin-height.

Answer (score 6):

Our eyes are fooling us. The density near the mode is high so that we can observe the variation more evidently. The density near the tail is so low so that we can not really spot anything. The following code performs sort of a "standardization", allowing us to visualize the variation on a relative scale.

```
set.seed(1)
x1 <- rnorm(1000L)
x2 <- rnorm(10000L)
x3 <- rnorm(100000L)
x4 <- rnorm(1000000L)

foo <- function(vec, title, brks) {
  ## bin estimation
  h <- hist(vec, breaks = brks, plot = FALSE)
  ## compute true probability between adjacent break points
  p2 <- pnorm(h$breaks[-1])
  p1 <- pnorm(h$breaks[-length(h$breaks)])
  p <- p2 - p1
  ## compute estimated probability between adjacent break points
  phat <- h$count / length(vec)
  ## compute and plot their absolute relative difference
  v <- abs(phat - p) / p
  ##plot(h$mids, v, main = title)
  ## plotting on log scale is much better!!
  v.log <- log(1 + v)
  plot(h$mids, v.log, main = title)
  ## invisible return
  invisible(list(v = v, v.log = v.log))
  }

par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
v1 <- foo(x1, title = 'Sample = 1E3', brks = 100)
v2 <- foo(x2, title = 'Sample = 1E4', brks = 500)
v3 <- foo(x3, title = 'Sample = 1E5', brks = 1000)
v4 <- foo(x4, title = 'Sample = 1E6', brks = 1000)
```

[image]

The relative variation is the lowest near the middle (toward 0), but very high near the two edges. This is well explained in statistics:

- We have more samples near the middle, so `(sample sd) : (sample mean)` there is lower;
- We have few samples near the edge, maybe 1 or 2, so `(sample sd) : (sample mean)` there is big.

---

**a little explanation on the log-transform I take**

`v.log = log(1 + v)`. Its Taylor expansion ensures that `v.log` is close to `v` for very small `v` around 0. As `v` gets larger, `log(1 + v)` gets closer to `log(v)`, thus the usual log-transform is recovered.

Comment: OP does not ask a standard statistical question here. We normally make vertical comparison between a set of histograms. Regarding the mean, we fix the break points, and see how frequency converges to probability on each bin as sample size grows. Regarding the variability, we fix the sample size and bins and check how the frequency changes with different random draws / replicates.

Comment: However, OP seeks a horizontal comparison here, that is, a comparison across bins in a specific histogram. Strictly speaking, we should first think about whether this is a valid question. Does it have a statistical interpretation at all? I find it hard. Because once we fix a histogram, we are just looking at a single realization without replicates. I agree that this thread is very interesting, but for all readers, just take my answer as a pure numerical investigation. I am not able to offer a firm statistical conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

`rnorm()` draws a *random* sample from a normal distribution.  The size of the sample is the first argument to `rnorm()`.  So if you do `hist(rnorm(10))` you will of course get something that doesn't look much like the normal bell curve because your sample size is so small.  If you do `hist(rnorm(1000))` it will be better and if you do `hist(rnorm(1e8))` your sample should approximate the curve quite well.

Comment: Thanks @Dan, yes, I know that. However, in each case, the approximation isn't nearly as good closer to the mean as it is towards the tails.

Comment: @Ameya - draw your plots a few times.  I suspect sometimes you will oversample near the mean and sometimes you will oversample near the tails.  Also, it is easy to visually spot 1% of oversampling near the mean because a 1% oversample there might be 100 draws.  However, an oversample of 1% in the tails might be only 1 draw and so would be hard to spot just by looking at a histogram.